# XML Parsing in PHP with domDocument

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a Xml which looks like

```
<theme>
<name>Test</name>
<thumb>http://ecample.com/bla.jpg</thumb>;
<template>
<name>Hello</name>
<html>
<body> 
<div id="hell">
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value="Type Some thing"/>
<input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" value="Button" />

<div class="hello">
<p>here is a paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="hello123">
    <p><a href="#">Click Me!</a>here is a paragraph again!</p>
</div>
<textarea name="hello"></textarea>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
<css> CODE STUFF </css>
<javascript> CODE STUFF </javascript>
</template>
<template>
<name>World!</name>
<html> CODE STUFF </html>
<css> CODE STUFF </css>
<javascript> CODE STUFF </javascript>
</template>
</theme>
```

I want to get all html tags as they are in the body tag. but when i get html tag using domDocument most of tags are missing. this is my code below

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML( $xml_file_string );//xml file loading here
    $themes = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "theme" );
    foreach( $themes as $theme )
    {
        $theme_name = $theme->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
        $theme_thumb = $theme->getElementsByTagName( "thumb" );
        $theme_name = $theme_name->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $theme_thumb = $theme_thumb->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo $theme_name.'<br>';
        echo $theme_thumb.'<br>';
        $templates = $theme->getElementsByTagName( "template" );
        foreach( $templates as $template )
        {
            $template_name = $template->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
            $template_name = $template_name->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $template_html = $template->getElementsByTagName( "html" );
            $template_html = $template_html->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $template_css  = $template->getElementsByTagName( "css" );
            $template_css  = $template_css->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $template_javascript = $template->getElementsByTagName( "javascript" );
            $template_javascript = $template_javascript->item(0)->nodeValue;
            echo $template_name.'<br>';
            echo html_entity_decode($template_html).'<br>';
            echo $template_css.'<br>';
            echo $template_javascript.'<br>';
        }
    }
```

and the result i am getting is like,

Test
http://ecample.com/bla.jpg
Hello
{{rating}} {{content}} here is a paragraph Click Me!here is a paragraph again!
CODE STUFF
CODE STUFF
World!
CODE STUFF
CODE STUFF
CODE STUFF

You can see here that most of html is not working here.. please help

Comment: Your XML file is corrupted.

Look at line `<thumb>http://ecample.com/bla.jpg</thumb>;` - see that semicolon?

Comment: @michail_w i put it wrongly but its not the issue. i have double checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to understand, that method `getElementsByTagName` and any other getter return  object (or array of objects) of class `DOMNode`. If it has content, but not wrapped in any tag, this content can be returned by `nodeValue` property. And you use it to get template name. But nodeValue doesn't contain html of children. You have to create it. Here is example:

```
$tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true)); 
$html = trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML());
```

so your code should be like:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $xml_file_string );//xml file loading here
$themes = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "theme" );
foreach( $themes as $theme )
{
    $theme_name = $theme->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
    $theme_thumb = $theme->getElementsByTagName( "thumb" );
    $theme_name = $theme_name->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $theme_thumb = $theme_thumb->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $theme_name.'<br>';
    echo $theme_thumb.'<br>';
    $templates = $theme->getElementsByTagName( "template" );
    foreach( $templates as $template )
    {
        $template_name = $template->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
        $template_name = $template_name->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $template_html = $template->getElementsByTagName( "html" );

        //HERE IS CHANGE
        $tmpHtml = new DOMDocument();
        $tmpHtml->appendChild($tmpHtml->importNode($template_html->item(0), true)); 
        $template_html = trim($tmpHtml->saveHTML());

        //REST OF CODE
    }
}
```

I've only made change for `$template_html`, but I think you can now do the rest.

Comment: it works .. Thanks a lot Sorry for that i cant rate you answer as i have less reputation as i am new to stack-overflow. but i appreciate your help :)